# Log when file is requested from server

Tags: ip-address, tracking, server-side, file-access

I need a way to log an entry into a database, everytime a particular file is requested from the server. The file can be any type, even images or other media.

Is it also possible to log which IP address or hostname has requested that file?

Comment: Lets say images such as JPG or PNG. But it should work with other types as well...  I'm talking about a regular HTTP request, such as when another site requests images from my server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the language? HTTP handler technology?

Example: `java/servlet, ruby/rails, php/apache`...

In either case you can analyze the log file easily: HTTP log files contain ip, file name, timestamp.

It would be a ten lines in `perl+DBI` to parse apache's config and count downloads into database. Stuck it int cron and be done.

Comment: Any language. Basically it should be standalone since I'm not running any server side scripts currently.

Comment: Yes you can. Why don't you grab awstats, btw? Google for it.